# Workaround for a "diverging implicit expansion" error in Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-2.10

With the following code I get a "diverging implicit expansion" error in Scala 2.10, even though there is an unique way to construct the implicit:

```
class Foo {
  trait Foo[A]
  abstract class Bar[A](implicit e: Foo[A])

  implicit val intFoo: Foo[Int] = ???
  implicit def pairFoo[A, B](implicit ea: Foo[A], eb: Foo[B]): Foo[(A, B)] = ???
  implicit def funcFoo[A, B](implicit ea: Foo[A], eb: Foo[B]): Foo[A => B] = ???
  implicit def arrayFoo[A](implicit e: Foo[A]): Foo[Array[A]] = ???
  def foo[A](implicit e: Foo[A]): Foo[A] = e
  class Bar1[A, B, Env](implicit eA: Foo[A], eB: Foo[B], eEnv: Foo[Env])
    extends Bar[(Array[Env], ((Int,A)) => B)]
}

> compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/aromanov/IdeaProjects/playground/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/aromanov/IdeaProjects/playground/src/main/scala/Foo.scala:15: diverging implicit expansion for type Foo1.this.Foo[(Array[Env], ((Int, A)) => B)]
[error] starting with method pairFoo in class Foo
[error]   class Bar1[A, B, Env](implicit eA: Foo[A], eB: Foo[B], eEnv: Foo[Env])
[error]                        ^
```

I've added a more specific implicit conversion, hoping it would be picked:

```
implicit def complexFoo[A, B, Env](implicit eA: Foo[A], eB: Foo[B], eEnv: Foo[Env]): Foo[(Array[Env], ((Int,A)) => B)] =
  pairFoo(arrayFoo(eEnv), foo[((Int, A)) => B])
```

This doesn't help. Neither does moving `complexFoo` and `Bar1` to a subclass of `Foo` in order to benefit from the higher [relative weight](http://eed3si9n.com/implicit-parameter-precedence-again). Passing the argument explicitly (`extends Bar[(Array[Env], ((Int,A)) => B)]()(complexFoo)`) does work, but I'd really like to avoid it (`Bar1` is actually generated code, and this would make generation more complex). So, is there another way to avoid the error?

This works fine in 2.11.5, but we can't remove 2.10 compatibility for now.

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
class Bar1[A, B, Env](implicit eA: Foo[A], eB: Foo[B], eEnv: Foo[Env])
  extends Bar[(Array[Env], ((Int,A)) => B)]
```

to

```
class Bar1[A, B, Env](implicit foo: Foo[(Array[Env], ((Int,A)) => B)])
  extends Bar[(Array[Env], ((Int,A)) => B)]
```

makes your code compile. Apparently, scalac 2.10 needs to be suggested directly the right implicit here (`foo`) and fails at building one by itself (out of `eA`, `eB`, `eEnv`).

Hope your code generation tool can generate just that.

Comment: Don't know enough of the implicits resolution internals to tell why this is so.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this means the example was oversimplified; I actually need to use `eA` etc. themselves in code. And adding `foo` instead of replacing them results in a lot of conflicting implicits.

Comment: You could try using shapeless'`Lazy` too, it usually solves a lot of implicit diverging expansions. But it doesn't deal well with type variables for now, so it may be a bit complicated (I thought `Lazy` was the solution first, but it turned out it wasn't necessary)